# "File (Field) Paths" module broken by "Media Browser Plus" 7.x-3.0-beta3

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-files

I have a strange behaviour when I want to upload files in a specific path.

I have created a new gallery photo on my Drupal website and I want to add many photos on this gallery. (Initially I'm not a Drupal developper...) I tried the first time to put directly all the files on the corresponding folder "sites/default/files/galleries/", but I didn't know after that how to insert these photos on the page of the gallery...

So, I have to use an Image Field to feed my gallery correctly... But I don't want the photos be uploaded on the default file folder ("sites/default/files"). All the files in the same folder is a very bad practice...
So, I use the "File (Field) Paths" (FFP) module (version 7.x-1.0-beta4). In the "File (Field) Path settings" I use "galleries/[node:field_gallery]" as "File path" and it doesn't work. The photos are still uploaded into "sites/default/files"... Even if I don't use pattern, but just a hard path like "galleries/test", this is the same. And also the same with the version "7.x-1.x-dev" of the FFP module.

Somebody had the same issue? Do you have a fix or a workaround?

To be clear, my initial need was just to create a gallery with a lot of photos. So, if I could use the FTP, put all my photos on the server and after insert these photos on my gallery would be the best solution. But it doesn't seem possible.
So, I don't want to use a simple Image Field because it would be crazy to add all the photos into the gallery one by one...And the Multi Upload module as well as the "File attach from server directory" function also put the files into "sites/default/files"...

So, I'm totally blocked now.

My Drupal version is 7.39.

Thanks a lot for your help! :)

---

UPDATE

I have found a workaround by updating the files path directly on database. Then, I just have to put my files in the path that I want. It works correctly, but as I'm not a Drupal developer, I'm a little bit afraid by potential side effects...

For information, I have made the test right now to add a photo into a gallery with an old version of the website (before updating Drupal from 7.22 to 7.34 and then 7.39, and before updating all the modules) and it works correctly natively!!
So, this situation is a regression bug because of the update of Drupal 7.22 or from one of the modules... A real challenge to identify the source of the regression by updating each element one by one... :(

Comment: Nobody has the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

So, I decided to come back to the old working version of my website and make the updates step by step. Firstly, update Drupal core from 7.22 and 7.39 and secondly update modules one by one.

With the Drupal core update, no problem! Then, I was lucky, because my intuition told me to try in the first place the update of the module "*FileField Sources*" and I could reproduce the bug.

So, the source of the bug is the update of the "*FileField Sources*" module from the 7.x-1.8 to the 7.x-1.10 version!

Could you explain me how I have to proceed please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I created an issue for this bug => https://www.drupal.org/node/2565855

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I made a mistake while doing my tests to identify the module at the origin of this bug.
And finally, the module which creates this bug is "Media Browser Plus", not "FileField Sources".

So, the good issue is this one => https://www.drupal.org/node/2595131